# Cancelling Skype4Py file transfer

Tags: python, file-transfer, skype, skype4py

I would like to cancel file transfer in python but I couldn't find any solution.
I use OnFileTransferStatusChanged function for it but I don't know how to actually cancel the file transfer.

---

```
import Skype4Py
import sys
import time
import os
from datetime import datetime

skype = Skype4Py.Skype(Transport = "dbus")
skype.Attach()

def OnFile(file, stts):
    # cancel file transfer
    # todo

def Main():
    while True:
        skype.OnFileTransferStatusChanged = OnFile
        time.sleep(0.5)
Main()
```

Comment: I am note completely sure, but based on this page (http://dev.skype.com/desktop-api-reference#OBJECT_FILETRANSFER) it looks like it's not possible.

Comment: thank you.i already realized.